# Use fputcsv but create many tables

Tags: php, fputcsv

If you have a single block of data, creating a table with `fputcsv` works great; it assumes the first row is a header and the following rows are of the same format.

But what do you do if you have multiple, differently formatted blocks of data you want to write out to a CSV:

```
Business Name: name-of-business.   Date: current date

Notes: single line of notes


Model | Product 
model1 | Product 1
model2 | Product 2
model3 | Product 3
```

The first line is basically a single line table with 4 columns and no headers
The second line is a single line table with 2 columns and no headers
Then the data - typical two column table with headers

Comment: Then your code that reads and processes that info needs to be a lot more carefully written. Simple, there is no Magic bullet

Comment: _"The first line is basically a single line table with 4 columns and no headers"_ - so pass an array containing four values to write into four different cells to `fputcsv` then. _"The second line is a single line table with 2 columns and no headers"_ - so pass an array containing two values to write into two different cells to `fputcsv` then.

Comment: You'd then have your own propitary definition of a CSV... it's not what I would expect from a CSV though, so don't blame on others if they can't understand your CSV :)

Comment: Agreed, this is a very unconventional CSV layout

Comment: I was hoping there was a string that would be interpreted as "stop table" or "start table" but I guess not.

Comment: CSV has a RFC, there's nothing more to expect from CSV than what's commented there I guess.

Comment: @HonkderHase please make an answer out of your comment, which seems to be the bottom line.  I was hoping there was a way to indicate to Excel that multiple separate tables were included in the CSV but this doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested:

> But what do you do if you have multiple, differently formatted blocks
> of data you want to write out to a CSV:

You'd then have your own propitary definition of a CSV... it's not what I would expect from a CSV though, so don't blame on others if they can't understand your CSV :)

CSV has a RFC, there's nothing more to expect from CSV than what's commented there I guess.